# Free groups: I'm trying to understand the proof of $F(X)$ being a group. How do I prove the map $\phi : F(X) \to F_0$ is a homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

[image]

$\sigma_x : F(X) \to F(X)$ is a permutation on $F(X)$ and $F_0= (\sigma_{x} : x \in X)$, the subgroup generated by $\sigma_x$.

The proof given is sketchy in the text I'm following (Algebra, Hungerford), and the steps missing very non-trivial to me so I'm filling in the details. I've started simply with taking any two (reduced?) words $w_1$ and $w_2$, then I'm assuming I have to consider the three possible cases their product can equal to. Starting with the first case, I'm having difficulty showing $\varphi(w_1 w_2) = \varphi(w_1) \varphi(w_2)$. Help, please?

Comment: You can't say anything at all about an arbitrary *permutation* of a group: it's just a bijection, not even a homomorphism. So I doubt your definition of $\sigma_X$. Instead, it looks like you should have a permutation $\sigma$ **of $X$**, which in turn induces an isomorphism $\sigma_X \colon F(X) \to F(X)$ in a hopefully obvious way. For a reduced word $w$, $\sigma_X(w)$ is the result of permuting the "symbols"(from $X$) in $w$, by applying $\sigma$ to each. It $w$ is reduced then the result of permuting its symbols will be reduced too. I have no idea what your $F_0$ is or what $\phi$ is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $w_1=x_1^{\delta_1}...x_n^{\delta_n}$ and $w_2=y_1^{\gamma_1}...y_m^{\gamma_m}$. What you need to do is to check that :

$$\varphi(w_1)\varphi(w_2):=|x_1^{\delta_1}|...|x_n^{\delta_n}||y_1^{\gamma_1}|...|y_m^{\gamma_m}| $$

is the same as $\varphi(w_1w_2)$. But this is clear since :

$$w_1w_2=x_1^{\delta_1}...x_n^{\delta_n}y_1^{\gamma_1}...y_m^{\gamma_m}\text{ whence } \varphi(w_1w_2):=|x_1^{\delta_1}|...|x_n^{\delta_n}||y_1^{\gamma_1}|...|y_m^{\gamma_m}|=:\varphi(w_1)\varphi(w_2) $$

So, if $\varphi$ is defined then the "morphism" property is obvious.

Beware, there is a little something here. One should demonstrate that $\varphi$ sending $x_1^{\delta_1}...x_n^{\delta_n}$ to $|x_1^{\delta_1}|...|x_n^{\delta_n}|$ is a well-defined function. Basically, it boils down to show that two words having the same reduction will have the same image by $\varphi$. I don't think there is something else than induction+tedious examination of cases to show that this is the case.